# Excel Conditional formatting highlight the bottom 3 values in colum C for each unique value in column A

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

This is just an example, but I have 3 columns. Name, Level and Impact. What I am trying to do is create a conditional formatting so the bottom 3 values in the impact column are highlighted for each unique value of Name and level combined (so =Name&Level would be my unique identifier). Is this even possible? below is a sliver of sample data to paint a clearer picture.

So one example would be these rows being highlighted for Eric2

```
Name    Level   Impact
Jack    1   -0.17 
Barry   1   -0.16 
Janice  2   -0.10 
Barry   3   -0.08 
Janice  4   -0.07 
Eric    4   -0.07 
Janice  1   -0.05
Eric    2   -0.04 <--Highlight
Jack    2   -0.04
Lisa    3   -0.04
Lisa    3   -0.04
Lisa    4   -0.03
Barry   2   -0.03
Jack    4   -0.03
Janice  1   -0.03
Janice  1   -0.03
Eric    2   -0.02 <--Highlight
Barry   2   -0.02
Eric    4   -0.02
Eric    4   -0.02
Barry   3   -0.02
Eric    4   -0.02
Janice  2   -0.02
Eric    1   -0.02
Eric    4   -0.02
Janice  3   -0.02
Eric    2   -0.02 <--Highlight
Eric    2   -0.02 <--Highlight
```

Thanks!

Comment: So given your example above which three would be highlighted?

Comment: @ScottCraner I think the OP means to highlight three values for each unique combination of `Name` and `Level`. Therefore in total many more than three values will be highlighted.

Comment: Yes, ImaginaryHuman is correct. 3 values highlighted for each unique combination of NAME and LEVEL ex. "Eric1"

Comment: please mark which in the data above would get high lighted.

Comment: @Matjoh33 How are ties handled? E.g. What if there is a 4-way-tie for lowest `Impact` for a certain `Name` and `Level` combination?

Comment: Does lowest mean lowest number ie -.17< -.02 or lowest on the sorted list in its relative position?

Comment: What about those that do not have 3, highlight them all? Ignore them?

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 The data above is just rounded to the 100th place. they're all much longer. But if they are the same I would like them all to be highlighted

Comment: Okay are you going to enter the search criteria in somewhere or just all of them need to be highlighted?

Comment: @ScottCraner There are over 3000 rows, I didn't want to post them all. If there are only 1 or 2 I would like them both highlighted. and by bottom 3 and mean the lowest number, ie. -.17 is lower than -.03

Comment: No criteria entered. Just the bottom 3 values for each unique combination of Name&Level highlighted

Comment: try this formula, the data you provided does not allow me to check because by your rules they all should highlight. `=AND(C2<=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$C$2:$C$29/(($B$2:$B$29=B2)*($A$2:$A$29=A2)),3),TRUE),A2=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$29)/(($B$2:$B$29=B2)*($A$2:$A$29=A2)),1)),B2=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$29)/(($B$2:$B$29=B2)*($A$2:$A$29=A2)),1)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(C2<=SMALL(IF(ROW($C$2:$C$33)-1=MATCH(IF(A2&B2=$A$2:$A$33&$B$2:$B$33,$C$2:$C$33),IF(A2&B2=$A$2:$A$33&$B$2:$B$33,$C$2:$C$33),0),IF(A2&B2=$A$2:$A$33&$B$2:$B$33,$C$2:$C$33)),3),TRUE())
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

At risk of over-simplifying, if OP is confident that all the impact values are distinct values (at least within a particular name and level) then it would be enough just to count how many values there are less than the current one.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,$A2,$B$2:$B$10,$B2,$C$2:$C$10, "<"&$C2)<3
```

On the other hand if there is a possibility of ties and OP wanted to highlight all rows corresponding to bottom 3 distinct values, could use this

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(($A$2:$A$10=$A2)*($B$2:$B$10=$B2)*($C$2:$C$10<$C2),$C$2:$C$10),$C$2:$C$10)>0))<3
```